# Usage of comparative with a set of adjectives

Tags: comparatives

Today I heard in a video a phrase that puzzled me a bit, specifically

> "...a more just and fair system..."

My previous understanding is that it should had been "fairer and juster" but now I have deep doubts having seen several similar combinations all over the internet.

Are both forms acceptable, and if not, why not?

Comment: Like *fun*, *just* is one of the one-syllable adjectives whose comparative uses *more* (I can't think of any beside these two). And because it's *more just*, they've used *more fair* for parallelism (you could also say *fairer and more just*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid.  "More just and fair" means "More (just and fair)", by which I mean that **more** is applied to both **just** and **fair**, giving you **juster and fairer**.

More importantly to me,

> **more just and fair**

is more elegant (and more eloquent) English than

> **juster and fairer**

although I believe most politicians would choose

> **a juster, fairer system**

Which is still more elegant English than **juster and fairer** while being less formal (and so more accessible) than **more just and fair**

Answer (score 2):

For most one-syllable adjectives, the proper way to form the comparative is to add *-er*. The comparative using *more* is always grammatical, but is used much less often. There are two exceptions that I can think of: *juster* and *funner* are not used much in contemporary English. (See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juster+than%2Cmore+just+than%2Cfunner+than%2Cmore+fun+than%2Cfairer+than%2Cmore+fair+than&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjuster%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20just%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfunner%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20fun%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfairer%20than%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20fair%20than%3B%2Cc0).)

The author is using *more just* because *juster* is very rare today, and is using *more fair* for parallelism with *more just*. He could also have said *"fairer and more just"*.